# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Multiple Cells with Different Colors

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am studying for a big exam and want to set priorities using conditional formatting. For example if C90, C91, C92 are blank than the color would be white; if C90, C91 are blank but C92 is not blank than the color would be be yellow; if C90, but C91 and C92 are not blank than the color would be red; and if all three are not blank than the color would be red. I want to apply this to all of the headers. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is super easy using the following steps:

1. Select the headers where you want the format to be applied
2. Choose the Format -> Conditional Formatting menu
3. Choose "format cells if" option
4. write your formula for yellow (for example:

   if(and(isblank(c90),isblank(c91),not(isblank(c92))))
5. Select the color yellow from the menu under the formula you just typed
6. Click on "add another rule"
7. Repeat 3-5 for the other colors you need

Good luck!